# The type argument for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am new in programming, when i write a code for particular function, i find this below error. Please help me to solve this error.

```
public IList<ScoreCardListItemTO> UpdateDate(bool IsScoreCardUpdate, bool IsInputHeaderUpdate, long ScoreCardId,
    long ScoreCardSubmitResponseId, long QuestionId, DateTime UpdatedOn)
{
    var parameters = new[]
    {
        new ObjectParameter("IsScoreCardUpdate", IsScoreCardUpdate ),
        new ObjectParameter("IsInputHeaderUpdate", IsInputHeaderUpdate ),
        new ObjectParameter("ScoreCardId", ScoreCardId ),
        new ObjectParameter("ScoreCardSubmitResponseId", ScoreCardSubmitResponseId ),
        new ObjectParameter("QuestionId", QuestionId),
        new ObjectParameter("UpdatedOn", UpdatedOn),
    };

    ObjectResult items = ExecuteEqmFunction("SyncUpdateOnColumn", string.Empty );
    return items;
}
```

the error show at this line

```
ObjectResult items = ExecuteEqmFunction("SyncUpdateOnColumn", string.Empty );
return items;
```

The error state that

> Error 42  The type arguments for method
>   'EQM.DataLayer.EqmRepository.ExecuteEqmFunction(string,
>   string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: you need to show the method `ExecuteEqmFunction` which is most probably a generic method.

Answer (score 2):

Just as it says , `ExecuteEqmFunction` is expecting 3 or 4 arguments, of which you supplied the first 2.

Try

```
ObjectResult items = ExecuteEqmFunction("SyncUpdateOnColumn", string.Empty, parameters);
```

I lack context, but I don't know why else you'd build `parameters` in that scope if not to supply it.

Comment: Isn't using `params` makes the third parameter an optional argument array ? If one parameter is missing, the compiler doesn't generate *cannot be inferred from the usage* error , AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too. But judging from the extra space there, I feel OP or someone messed with a third parameter that used to be there, or OP is inexperienced and didn't give us exactly the code that generated the error, but code that he was in the process of playing with. Not sure.

Comment: This error is shown for generic methods. Since `T` is not part of the parameters (which is the only way to be inferred by the compiler) he must specify the type argument explicitly for this generic method.

Answer (score 2):

As I found in the definition of the error when editing your question **because it is not visible otherwise**.

The method `ExecuteEqmFunction<T>` is generic and expects a type `T`.  Generic method infers the type only from the arguments you pass. Since you don't have any argument with type T, you need to specify that type explicitly:

```
 ObjectResult items = ExecuteEqmFunction<ObjectResult>("SyncUpdateOnColumn", 
                                                                 string.Empty, parameters);
```

Assuming `T` is the return type for that method.